# Animation for Layer in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, animation, uibezierpath

I masked an image with BezierPath.
I want to animate that mask image.

My code is as follow:

```
    UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(84.95, 205.11)];
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(122.89, 232.14) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(84.95, 205.11) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(110.81, 223.56)];
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(124.33, 233.04) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(123.37, 232.46) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(123.85, 232.78)];
    [bezierPath closePath];

    CAShapeLayer *maskImage = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskImage.path = bezierPath.CGPath;
    maskImage.fillColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    _myImageView.layer.mask = maskImage;

    CAShapeLayer *border = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    border.path = bezierPath.CGPath;
    border.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    border.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    border.lineWidth = 5;
    [_myImageView.layer addSublayer:border];
```

**How can I animate this?**

**Thank you**

Comment: please show your coding of  bezierPath

Comment: @user3182143, I added code for bezierPath.

Comment: @user2526811 Do you want to animate the drawing of this bezier path ??

Comment: @SiddharthSunil, yes or **_myImageView.layer.mask = maskImage** ...

Comment: Kindly check my answer brother.

Answer (score 0):

Use following piece of code:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CAShapeLayer *animationLayer;

- (IBAction)drawPattern:(id)sender{
[self setup];

[self.animationLayer removeAllAnimations];

CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
pathAnimation.duration = 10.0;
pathAnimation.fromValue = @(0);
pathAnimation.toValue = @(1);
[self.animationLayer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"strokeEnd"];
}

- (void)setup{
[self.animationLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
self.animationLayer = nil;

UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(84.95, 205.11)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(122.89, 232.14) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(84.95, 205.11) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(110.81, 223.56)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(124.33, 233.04) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(123.37, 232.46) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(123.85, 232.78)];

CAShapeLayer *pathLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

// provide frame & bounds so that path can be drawn over that.
pathLayer.frame = CGRectMake(35, 100, 250, 200);
pathLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(35, 100, 250, 200);
pathLayer.path = bezierPath.CGPath;
pathLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
pathLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
pathLayer.lineWidth = 6.f;
pathLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;

[self.view.layer addSublayer:pathLayer];
[self setAnimationLayer:pathLayer];
}
```

Please let me know if this works for you & also if anything else comes up.

Comment: Thank for your answer but this will only animates the Border not the path

Comment: @user2526811 this will draw the path with animation.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your code try below one

```
CAShapeLayer *pathLayer;
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

shapeLayer.path = [aPath CGPath];
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor];
shapeLayer.fillColor = nil;
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5.0f;
shapeLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel;

[myImageView.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
pathLayer = shapeLayer;
CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
pathAnimation.duration = 3.0;
pathAnimation.fromValue = @(0.0f);
pathAnimation.toValue = @(1.0f);
[pathLayer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"strokeEnd"];
```

Answer (score 0):

We can animate the image with path using CABasicAnimation.

CABasicAnimation has position,path,transform,opacity,shadow......which including all layers keypaths,shape layer keypaths,CA layer keypaths,Text layer keypaths,Mask layer keypaths,UIView layer keypaths,Effect,Emit and replicator keypaths.

**According to your question for drawing path we can use path and strokeEnd.But most prepare strokeEnd for accessing shape style properties.**

**So I think strokeEnd is the best one for animating the mask image with bezier path.**

Below I give the code for path and strokeEnd also I diffrecicate both.

If I use animationWithKeyPath is [path](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAShapeLayer/path)

> The shape to be rendered and animatable.It is specifying the shape path.

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
animation.fromValue = @(0);
animation.toValue = @(1);
animation.duration = 6.0f;
[maskImage addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animatePath"];
```

> The Path is a collection of individual components like lines and arcs that can be drawn and also animated.It is fundamental concept of Quartz 2D.

In below code I use strokeEnd

> Generally if we want to access the shape style properties we can use
>   strokeEnd
>
> The relative location at which to stop stroking the path and animatable.

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
animation.fromValue = @(0);
animation.toValue = @(1);
animation.duration = 6.0f;
[maskImage addAnimation:animation forKey:@"strokeEnd"];
```

> The value of this property must be in the range 0.0 to 1.0. The default value of this property is 1.0.

Also [strokeEnd](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAShapeLayer/fillColor) defines following thing

> Combined with the strokeStart property, this property defines the subregion of the path to stroke. **The value in this property indicates the relative point along the path at which to finish stroking while the strokeStart property defines the starting point**.